# Why is Fear the Walking Dead skipping a week?

Tags: behind-the-scenes, the-walking-dead, fear-the-walking-dead

The first episode of *Fear the Walking Dead* aired last Sunday (the 23rd).  The second episode aired last night (the 30th).  Next Sunday (the 6th), AMC will replay the first two episodes.  The third episode will air on the following Sunday, the 13th).

Why are they skipping a week before showing the third episode?

Comment: presumably because of labor day in the US. most networks don't like showing new episodes on weeks with holidays. especially on a long three day weekend.

Comment: Is this on topic?

Comment: @Boelabaal - Of course.  Why wouldn't it be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The official [Twitter account](https://www.twitter.com/feartwd) of *Fear the Walking Dead* retweeted the following *Inquisitr* article:

- [***Fear the Walking Dead* is on Hiatus for Labor Day, Returns September 13**](https://www.inquisitr.com/2380157/fear-the-walking-dead-is-on-hiatus-for-labor-day-returns-september-13/)

> Unfortunately, with Labor day falling next weekend, it appears AMC has decided to put *Fear The Walking Dead* on hiatus for one week.

The fact that the article was retweeted by the series' own official Twitter account would seem to confirm that Labour Day is the official reason for the skipped week.

Comment: Note that the actual article title is "*Fear the Walking Dead* is on Hiatus for Labor Day, Returns September 13", but I couldn't bring myself to spell it that way.

Comment: This is inquistor's given reason, but does not include an official quote from AMC/producers. Is there anything from them saying that it's because of Labor day?

Comment: @phantom42 : See edit.

Comment: @Praxis - I can't in good conscience accept this answer unless it includes a quote of some kind.  I think you're right, but it is almost a link-only answer right now.

Comment: @WadCheber : How about now?

Comment: @Praxis -Perfect.

Comment: @WadCheber : Thanks.  Enjoy the reruns until the 13th. ;-)

Comment: @Praxis  Nooooooooo!!!! Although I do appreciate the idea that the end of this season of *Fear the Walking Dead* will butt up against the season six premier of *The Walking Dead*.

Comment: @Praxis: Labour is a political party in the UK. The only correct spelling of the US holiday is Labor Day.

Comment: @Martha: That's false.  It's a holiday here in Canada too, where the spelling is "Labour Day".